# How to access Axios error response object in catch clause?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, try-catch

I recently upgraded to axios 0.23.0 and I am now receiving an error when trying to access the error response object in a catch clause. This is where I am getting the error:

```
  const loginUser = async (userData: UserPayload): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const result = await login(userData);
      const { token } = result.data;
      localStorage.setItem('jwtTokenTS', token);
      setupAxios(token);
      const decoded: User = jwt_decode(token);
      setUser(decoded);
      setAuthenticated(true);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response.status === 404) {
        window.alert('User not found');
      } else if (err.response.status === 401) {
        window.alert('Incorrect password');
      } else {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  };
```

The "login" function on line 3 is my axios request as seen below:

```
export async function login(user: UserPayload): Promise<AxiosResponse<{ token: string }>> {
  return axios.post(`${bConfig.backend}/login`, user);
}
```

The exact error I receive is when trying to access "err.response.status":

> Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)
> (local var) err: unknown

Any ideas on how to get rid of this error will be appreciated, I have tried typing the error at the catch clause but typescript doesn't like this either.

Comment: first of all type err: <```catch(err:any)```. that should fix the issue. Then if you want to check that the error is an Axios error checks this: ```.catch((err: Error | AxiosError) {
  if (axios.isAxiosError(error))  {
    // Access to config, request, and response
  } else {
    // Just a stock error
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: As mentioned by @matas-ramanauskas in another answer, a built-in type guard available from Axios (see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3546/files). The built in type guard should be able to handle also when the object being checked is null since `error.isAxiosError` will return an error is error is null.

I've also updated the code below to check whether `error` is not null or not undefined before checking the `isAxiosError` property.

---

Since TypeScript 4.4, catch clause variables are now defaulted from any to unknown type unless configured not to. This allows for safer handling as it forces users to check the type of caught value in the catch clause before being used. To get rid of that error, you need to use a type guard to narrow down the possible types of the object to let TypeScript know what type it is dealing with.

You can do something like this:

```
const isAxiosError = (error: unknown): error is AxiosError => {
  return error && (error as AxiosError).isAxiosError;
};

try {
  // ...
} catch (err) {
  if (isAxiosError(err) && err.response) {
    if (err.response.status === 404) {
      window.alert('User not found');
    } else if (err.response.status === 401) {
      window.alert('Incorrect password');
    } else {
      console.error(err);
    }
  } else {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

You can check out the guide I made specifically for this scenarios.
https://www.linkedin.com/posts/michael-bonon_handling-typed-errors-in-typescript-44-activity-6865161464236400640-MkWB

Comment: I think your answer is great @Mike_B, however, I'm stuck on a similar problem but not sure if I am handing it okay. Do you think you could take a look at my issue over here https://stackoverflow.com/q/70751518/15492085 ? I'd really appreciate it man! Great Linkedin post by the way, very declarative!

Comment: Thanks @DOZBORNE! I added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Michael [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70735731/2227743) the reasoning and solution well. However his type guard function is not 100% correct and might cause problems (like `(error as AxiosError).isAxiosError` will give you error if you try to catch something like `throw "abc";`). I suggest using default axios type guard available since v0.21.1 December 21, 2020  (https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (err) {
  if (axios.isAxiosError(err) && err.response) {
   ...
  }
}
```