# Cannot get type of error which comes from axios catch in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

Project Service responsible for backend Project Endpoinst, I've moved postData function to Project Service because of raising readibility for question. When I am trying to use projectService.postRequest(), in the catch block  cannot get type of error. Error's type is any. What am I doing wrong ?

[image: Project Service Class]

[image: Usage of Project Service]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access Axios error response object in catch clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69588020/how-to-access-axios-error-response-object-in-catch-clause)

Comment: No, it isnt @some-user. The main goal is to get type of error